# What is a good resource for learning the System.Speech APIs?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

In C# 3.5 System.Speech.dll was added for doing text-to-speech and speech-to-text conversions. Searching on the internet I've found a few blog posts about getting started, but are there any good resources for learning more about this technology? (Other than the obligatory [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.aspx).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a decent article on it here:

http://www.mperfect.net/speechSamples/

Should be enough to get going. Other than that, as you say, look through the MSDN docs, familiarise yourself with the API, and try stuff out.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN Magazine had a couple of [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx) that might be helpful, as well.